# Improve my query to make it more efficient

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at this query and try to give me any other ideas that will give the exact same results more efficiently.

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE username NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT username
    FROM users, friends 
    WHERE 'user1' IN (you,friend,username) 
      AND you     IN ('user1',username) 
      AND friend  IN ('user1',username))
  AND username <> 'user1'
```

[Here's a live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65b95/6).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: is there any other way to re-write this code?
it works but it doesn't look efficient to me.
How can I write it using NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, but I'm new to this website

Comment: CAn you post the table definitions for the users and friends tables?

Comment: yes, it's in the live demo

Comment: this makes no sense to me at all Can you explain, in simple terms, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to return all the usernames that is not a friend with 'user1' including 'user1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly isn't efficient - you have a cartesian in your sub-select. Its not particularly clear from your query what you're actually trying to achieve. If you described the problem, it would be much more helpful. Still, I'm guessing that you're trying to find all users who aren't friends with 'user1'..? In which case this should work:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE username NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT you 
FROM friends 
WHERE friend = 'user1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT friend 
FROM friends 
WHERE you = 'user1') 
AND username <> 'user1'
```